# subtract two data frames containing NA's to get zero where equal

Tags: r, vectorization, na

I would like to compare two big numeric data frames by way of subtraction, i.e. vectorization which is the fastest, in order to figure out where the two are equal.
For my purposes, if the two contain NA's in the same positions they are equal in this position.
However when subtracting, instead of zero I would get NA.
Is there a way of telling R that NA-NA = 0?

For example:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,NA))
df2 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,NA))

df1-df2:

x  y
0  0
0  0
0 NA
```

Comment: I am not saying that rigorously it should be, but I want to force R to understand that for my purposes, if there are NA's in the same position it should recognize that the two are equal, in other words their difference is zero. Your command would slow down the operation of df1-df2. Maybe there is really no other way to do this, though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are dealing with numerical dataframes, it's best to first convert them to matrices for speed. We can then use the following element-wise logic:

```
mat1 <- as.matrix(df1)
mat2 <- as.matrix(df2)

equal_mat <- (mat1 == mat2) | (is.na(mat1) & is.na(mat2))
colnames(equal_mat) <- names(df1)
```

**Result:**

```
         x     y
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Data** (Modified the data to show that it works as expected for normal comparisons):

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c(1,3,3), y = c(4,6,NA))
df2 = data.frame(x = c(2,2,3), y = c(4,5,NA))
```